# React- connected-router could not show images from base name

Tags: reactjs, connected-react-router

I have changed to basename to be '/test'

now I could not open local images that in the same folder

history.ts

```
import { History, createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history: History = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: '/test'
});
```

from home.tsx ( this is not working)

```
  <img width="100%" height="600px" alt="" src="./image.jpg" />
```

how can I make sure local images will use the base images also

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 possible solution

1. use require
   `<img width="100%" height="600px" alt="" src="{require("./image.jpg")}" />`
2. update the manifest.json with `start_url="/basename"`
3. add `"hompage":"/basename"`  to package.json